# how to access :after and :before properties of box-shadow in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I am making a web page with all these typical user account sign up form. I want to try some new technique for the submit button. I thought of using a `css` `div` for the submit button, which will change its shadow when clicked. I found an awesome link: http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects
 for making shadows, and I also found out by using `object.boxShadow`

I can change the shadow properties, but the thing is I am unaware of how to change the `:after` and `:before` property of the shadow.
Whenever I change the property with `onclick` or `onmousedown` events, it gets applied for the whole div box and I dont want that. I want just the corner of the box to change the shadow when clicked.

It would be great if someone helped. Thank you. :-)

PS: if the question is already asked and answered, please do paste the link.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not need to find javascript or jquery for that. You simply apply css class to your div by jquery like, if you are having

```
.effect:after{css properties}
```

you can add that class to your div using jquery:

```
$('.div').addClass('effect');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for this solution, actually i use to do that too. This way your css resides only in your css files, not in js ones (and your js file doesn't become ugly :D )